# jQuery: adding one element in many div of the same class

Tags: jquery

With jQuery latest one:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Could someone explain what are the differences between:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.produit').append('<img src="img.png" alt="altimg" />');
});
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.produit').append($('img').attr({ 'src':'img.png', 'alt':'altimg' }));
});
```

=> the first code works, but the second adds the image *many times* (seven times exactly) then throws a JavaScript Exception:

- under Chrome: "`Cannot read property 'cycleW' of undefined`"
- under Firefox 10: "`next is undefined`"

...

I'm a JavaScript beginner and I thought those two codes would do the same...

...
any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second code has an error.

It should be:

```
$('<img>', ...);
```

To *create* a new element the tag needs angle brackets around it!

As written, it's *selecting* every *existing* image tag on the page, and appending them to every instance of `.produit`.

Ideally you should also use the map version of `$('<tag>')`, rather than calling `.attr` afterwards:

```
$('<img>', {src: 'img.png', alt:'altimg'}).appendTo('.produit');
```

Comment: So it resulted in a infinite loop (because once an image was added, it could maybe find it and add itself once again). Ok got it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`'<img src="img.png" alt="altimg" />'` is the string version of `$('img').attr({ 'src':'img.png', 'alt':'altimg' })`.

There isn't a loop in the second code block but if there are more than one `.produit` elements then they will all get an image element appended to them.

To inspect the second code block a little closer:

- `$('img')`: this creates an `img` element
- `.attr({ 'src':'img.png', 'alt':'altimg' })`: this gives the new `img` element a `src` and an `alt` attribute.

It's useful to create your DOM elements like this if you are allowing user input to become part of the element. It helps against injection attacks where a user could alter the HTML of your page if you just concocted a string of their input.

### Update

Alnitak had a very good observation that `$('img')` selects all the `img` elements in the DOM and `$('<img />')` actually creates an `img` element.

Comment: better yet, use `$('<img>', {src: 'img.png', alt:'altimg'})`

Comment: I was thinking about adding that example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$('img') selects all the images in your html then .attr sets the attributes.
If you want you can select the img element like this :

```
$('img[src=img.png][alt=altimg]')
```

but it WON'T create a new element. it will select one in your document.

As for your .append call, it appends the html you pass in argument to your element.